# Unable to install most recent gvim 8.1 on Ubuntu

Tags: gvim, installing, linux-ubuntu

On Ubuntu, when I do `vim --version` in the terminal I get:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jan  6 2019 14:05:44)
>
> Included patches: 1-699

However, when I do `gvim --version` I get:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)
>
> Included patches: 1-1453

In trying to update the Vim version underneath my gvim installation, I thought it would be as simple as re-installing gvim with `sudo apt-get install gvim`. However, that gives me:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package gvim is a virtual package provided by:
> vim-gtk 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1
> vim-athena 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1
> vim-gtk3 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1
> You should explicitly select one to install.
>
> E: Package 'gvim' has no installation candidate

That is, only the gvim version that I already have installed appears as available to me. At the [official page](https://www.vim.org/download.php) I found mentions of how to install gvim8.1 for Windows, but not for Linux.

So, how could I update gvim to 8.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually able to update gvim to 8.1 on Ubuntu 18 by following the same as this question asked in the past about older versions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/875003/ubuntu-16-10-repository-providing-vim-8

Basically, I followed the first option pointed by that answer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

After doing the above, `gvim --version` gives me:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jan 07 2019 10:34:10)
>   Included patches: 1-744
>   Modified by jonathon.fernyhough@york.ac.uk
>   Compiled by jonathon.fernyhough@york.ac.uk
>   Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included

Comment: You should accept your own answer.

Comment: @Ralf Perhaps because I have low rep, but the site requires me to wait 2 days before doing so.